# Sharing mounted FreeNAS volume

Tags: sharing, ftp, freenas

We have a FreeNAS in the office which we're using as an FTP server, but the speeds are incredibly slow for clients trying to download from it.

When I tried downloading directly (via OS X ftp server) from one of our OSX machines it was much faster.

So I'd like to try using the Mac as the FTP server, and the FreeNAS for storage.

But when I mount the FreeNAS with AFP, it cannot be shared via OSX ftp service.

What can we do?

Or is there a way to fix the low speed of the FreeNAS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Before giving up on a standalone FreeNAS machine, try the included [speed testing tool](http://doc.freenas.org/index.php/Iperf) `iperf` to determine the best protocol for your network:

> Iperf is a utility for measuring maximum TCP and UDP bandwidth performance. It can be used to chart network throughput over time. For example, you can use it to test the speed of different types of shares to determine which type best performs on your network.
>
> FreeNAS® includes the Iperf server. To perform network testing, you will need to install an Iperf client on a desktop system that has network access to the FreeNAS® system.

Do you know which alternative protocol your clients could use to connect to your FreeNAS box? Are you restricted to only File Transfer Protocol (FTP)?

This recent discussion talks about the some factors affecting FreeNAS, [FreeNAS Poor Network Performance](http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/296566-freenas-poor-network-performance).

Comment: I will check that, but IS there a way to share a mounted FreeNAS volume? That would be the quickest solution for us for now.

Answer (score 0):

I found one way to share the mounted FreeNAS volume: by sharing the `/Volumes/` folder.